# Box-API:No stream_position in V2 admin_logs events api

Tags: box-api

I have been using v2 of the Box API to get the events of individual users. Recently I read about the provisioning of `admin_logs` in v2 API that provide the logs for all users solely from the auth_token of the admin. I wanted to give that a try and found the following issue:

The `admin_logs` API response does not carry any `stream_position`, unlike the normal user API. How can the client then reliably get all the logs? One obvious way is to use the returned `chunk-size` as the offset in the next call to the API. Is this a reliable approach?

Also, what about the consideration of duplicate logs. The normal user API was prone to sending duplicate logs as suggested by the Box documentation. I catered for it in my application. But now for the `admin_logs` there is no stream position. Does that mean that there will be no duplicate logs in the `admin_logs` responses? Will the offsets guarantee that no duplicates are returned?

Also, how will long polling work in the case of `admin_logs`? I tried to fetch a long poll URL using admin auth_token with the `admin_logs` specifier

```
curl -XOPTIONS https://api.box.com/2.0/events?stream_type=admin_logs
```

but this returns a 500 `internal_server_error`.

When this failed I tried to get a long polling URL with admin auth_token but without the `admin_logs` specifier

```
curl -XOPTIONS https://api.box.com/2.0/events
```

this call is successful and returns a long poll URL but unfortunately I do NOT get the updates of all users on this polling URL. Seems like it only reports the events for that specific admin. Is there any way to enable long-polling on `admin_logs`?

Answer (score 2):

> How can the client then reliably get all the logs?

[Enterprise events](http://developers.box.com/docs/#events-get-events-in-an-enterprise) use the `created_before` and `created_after` properties in place of the `stream_position`.  The  `created_after` property is a close analog of `stream_position`.

> What about the consideration of duplicate logs?

You may receive duplicate enterprise events.  You can use the `event_id` to ensure that you have a distinct set of records.

**EDIT**

> How will long polling work in the case of `admin_logs`?

Per seanrose below, long-polling of enterprise events is a work in progress.

Comment: Here is an official note you can add on long polling for admin_logs: it's not yet supported, but we're working on it. No current ETA.

Comment: @john Hoerr, For the `created_after` property to work correctly, can it be assumed that the log events are always received in the ascending(moving forward)sort time order?

Comment: I would assume that they'll arrive out of order, but that everything  returned will have occured after `created_after`.  The [event object](http://developers.box.com/docs/#events-event-object) example shows a couple of useful sorting properties: `created_at` and `recorded_at`.  These don't appear in class documentation -- an oversight perhaps? -- so I'd verify that that information is returned with the event data.

Comment: So since the events can be out of order,basically in order for this approach to work correctly, we need to look at the `created_at`property of every event in a chunk and calculate the latest timestamp. Then that timestamp needs to be used as the `created_after` property in the next call to the API

Comment: Yes, that's how I would approach it.